# SFMC Custom Activity - save/publish/validate/execute endpoints not called

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I am trying to build a simple Journey Builder activity, however, at this time, it looks like SFMC is not calling any of my endpoints.  I have reviewed other similar questions, but none of the answers have helped me so far.

I simply don't see any contact attempt on the endpoints.  They work fine if I try to access them via my browser or Postman.

Below is my config.json

```
{
    "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
    "metaData": {
       "icon": "static/images/icon.png",
       "iconSmall": "static/images/iconSmall.png"
    },
    "type": "REST",
    "lang": {
       "en-US": {
           "name": "My Activity Name",
           "description": "My Activity Description"
       }
    },
    "arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "inArguments": [],
            "outArguments": [],
            "url": "https://my.endpoint.com/execute",
            "verb": "POST",
            "format": "json",
            "useJwt": true,
            "timeout": 10000
        }
    },
    "configurationArguments": {
       "save": {
            "url": "https://my.endpoint.com/save",
            "body": "",
            "verb": "POST",
            "useJwt": false
        },
        "validate": {
            "url": "https://my.endpoint.com/validate",
            "body": "",
            "verb": "POST",
            "useJwt": false
        }
    },
    "userInterfaces": {
       "configModal": {
           "height": 200,
           "width": 300,
           "fullscreen": false
       }
    }
}
```

I confirmed that I am indeed setting `metaData.isConfigured = true` before I call `connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);` in my customActivity.js file.

If anybody has any kind of insights, or spots some glaring error I have missed, I would be most grateful.

Comment: @Data_Kid the service is hosted on an SSL server via port 443.  Port 22 is usually for SFTP service, no?

Comment: My bad have you registered the end points in your installed package? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/define-jb-extension-app-center.htm

Comment: Yes, the endpoint has been registered. I have re-created the installed package and component for good measure, but to no avail.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this problem?